# Making a vector reactive

Tags: r, shiny

I apologise in advance for not having a minimal reproducible example. I tried to make one but didn't manage to reproduce the error.

So I have 2 scripts (ui.R and server.R) in the same folder. At the very start of the server script I want to make a vector a which will fill itself with inputs from 2 selectInputs in the ui-script.

```
#ui
shinyUI(fluidPage(
fluidRow(
    column(selectInput(inputId = "input1",
                       label = "This is input 1",
                       choices = c("bad","neutral","good"))
    column(selectInput(inputId = "input2",
                       label = "This is input 2",
                       choices = c("bad","neutral","good"))

#server
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
a <- c(input$input1, input$input2)
})

b <- b[a]
```

The user interface part is not the problem, the server part is. When I run the app I get this error:

```
Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext() : 
  Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)
```

So I realize I have to make this vector a somehow reactive but I fail to see how. I tried using the function `reactive`:

```
#server
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
a <- reactive({
       c(input$input1, input$input2)
     })    
})
```

But off course then I get this error because a is no longer a vector but a function.

```
invalid subscript type 'closure'
```

Comment: To get the vector, do `a()`, can't really tell where you are using it from the `server.R` you posted

Comment: You're right about the way to assign it in a reactive statement. However, you can only ever call it inside another reactive/observe/render environment, and when you do, you have to call it like a function with no arguments, as NicE showed in his comment. 

If you want to make Shiny apps, I absolutely think you should go through the Shiny tutorial here, http://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/lesson1/
It's an amazing tutorial and absolutely worth going through the whole thing IMO.

Comment: The tutorial certainly looks worth looking into, but problem is I'm more in a adhoc situation at the moment: I made a script and wanted to add some very basic interactive elements. I'm a bit short on time and learning shiny in a good way will take (too much) time. But thanks anyways for your answer.

Comment: @NicE, I updated the script. A couple of lines later I use the vector a made of inputs to index another (non-reactive) vector b which I already had before.

Comment: try `b[a()]` in your update, using the reactive statement for a above

Comment: @NicE I did but it still fails, probably because I do something with a after the subsetting. After the indexing I  make a new list c of which a is an element. So c <- list(a(),b). Should I instead treat b as a reactive vector too since it's built off a reactive vector? So should I try c <- list(a(), b())?

I still don't get the difference with the situation in [tutorial lesson 4](http://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/lesson4/). Just above the launch part input$var is used without any brackets.